# Kung Fury VHS effect

Tags: video, after-effects, filter

I hope everybody seen this **amazing** trailer of upcoming Swedish masterpiece:

[image: KUNG FURY]

[FULL HD TRAILER](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72RqpItxd8M)

So, I wonder, how to achieve this cool video effect. Please, pay attention on the edges:

[image]

The image some kinda decomposes into 2 channels.
How to reproduce this?

Comment: I have no answer for you, but this movie looks frickin' great!!

Comment: @BrettFromLA, yeah, right! They gathered 620k$ on Kickstarter instead of 200r$! It's in post-production now.

Comment: @DrMayhem, pls, check screenshot
https://yadi.sk/i/4F-plZn2cjF4y

Comment: @DrMayhem, possibly, but I think not effect of lenses, 'cause everything was shot in a single room using chroma-key (check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ed3dnF5wZkU).

Comment: @BrettFromLA, you can check my research )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a research I found the *solution*. 
Watch this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5PGkWjqAZ9s).

**At a glance:**

1. Create **Adobe After Effects** project.
2. Add **"Channel set"** effect.
3. Duplicate layer 3 times.
4. Adjust each layer to show only one channel (Red/Green/Blue).
5. Set **Blending Mode** as **Screen**.
6. Add transformation for each layer. Play with rotation/scale.

Voila! Check my example.

**Original frame (sorry for low bitrate)**
[image]

**RGB shifted**
[image]

I think it's cool as hell!

Comment: That's brilliant! Nicely researched.

Comment: @DrMayhem, thanks! Today I celebrate ) Gonna use it in music video producing.